# What does it mean to say in PAC learning that if the running time of the algorithm is polynomial in 1/e and 1/d, the sample size must be also poly

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

In the context of PAC learning, why it is true to say that if an algorithm *A* is a PAC-learning algorithm, then the sample size required by it must also be polynomial, i.e., how to properly interpret the highlighted part in purple? And what implications can be made from the statement? [image]

Comment: If the sample size increases faster than polynomial, then *perforce* any calculations you make with the full sample *must* also increase faster than polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! So that means when you have an algorithm that runs in polynomial time in terms of 1/epsilon and 1/delta and guarantees PAC, then the concept class must be PAC learnable as the complexity of the algorithm is an upper bound of the sample size, assuming all samples are given to the algorithm?